# How to install canon imageclass mf4412 printer on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: printing

I am new to Ubuntu.

How can I install canon imageclass mf4412 printer on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: There are no official Linux drivers for the [Canon imageCLASS MF4412](http://search-hk.canon-asia.com/canon__hk_en__hk_en/search.x?ct=Support&hf=category%09zubaken&d=DOWNLOADS&q=imageCLASS+MF4412)

Comment: @ThatGuy: That actually sounds like the answer to the question (albeit probably not what OP expected). Would you mind converting it to an actual answer?

Comment: Happy to tomorrow. I thought perhaps there might be a 3rd party postscript driver or something. I can research more in the morning to make certain. :)

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Looks like I might have been wrong.  I managed to track down a UFR driver.  I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @ThatGuy's solution, it did not work for me.

So, I searched a little more, found this link;

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/imageclass-mf4450?tab=drivers_downloads

Downloaded the driver (UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V3.40) from here, which is for MF4450, as it says. But it worked for me.

After extracting the driver files, you will find an `install.sh` in its root folder. Just `sudo ./install.sh`, and it sets up everything for you.

And then you should find your printer in Settings > Printers up and ready for the job.

Comment: it worked like a charm, this is helping many of us. Thanking you!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [UFR II Driver](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html) from the [Canon-Asia](http://www.canon-asia.com) site.

Once downloaded:

1. `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libxml2:i386 lib32z1 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386 python-cups`
2. `tar zvxf Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_uk_EN.tar.gz`
3. `cd Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian`
4. `dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.60-1_amd64.deb`
5. `apt-get -f install`
6. Reboot, just to be sure.
7. Open your browser and go to the local CUPS Page (http://localhost:631/admin)
8. Click on "Add Printer" (if you're asked for a username/pass use yours or root credentials)
9. From "Local Printers" choose `Imageclass MF4412`
10. Click "Continue"
11. Click "Continue" again
12. The model should be set on this page, if not, select it manually
13. Click "Add Printer"
14. Click on "Set Default Options"
15. You may need to wait for up to 30 seconds at this point
16. Click the "Maintenance" drop down menu, and click "Print Test Page"

If all went well, the printer should print the page successfully.

*Please note: I cannot test this, so it's an "as-is" answer.  If it works, great!*